# Probability of event occurring multiple times

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate the probability of exactly $8$ identical independent events occurring if each has a $25\%$ chance of occurring.

To simplify, if I were rolling a four-sided die $8$ times, what would be the probability be of rolling a $1$ only once through the probability of rolling a $1$ on the die $8$ times? I'd like to create a data table with $x$ being $1$ through $8$ and $f(x)$ being the probability. It seems like a normal distribution.

Comment: This is a job for the Binomial Distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution . Your intuition is in the right place: In a sense that can be made precise, this distribution is approximately normal.

Comment: If you are familiar with the language R, then you can look up some functions related to the binomial distribution like `dbinom`. Also, formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

It follows a **binomial distribution**.

If $X$ is distributed according to the *binomial distribution* with number of trials $n$ ($8$, in your case) and probability $p$ ($0.25$ for you), then $X\sim\mathcal {Bin}(n,p)$ means:

$$\mathsf P(X=r) \,=\, \binom{n}{r}\,p^r\,(1-p)^{n-r} \qquad \text{where }r\in\{0,..,n\}, 0\text{ otherwise}$$

Where $\dbinom{n}{r} = \dfrac{n}{r!\,(n-r)!}$, which is also often represented as: ${^n{\rm C}_r}$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).